# Cloud run over reverse proxy throws 404

Tags: reverse-proxy, google-cloud-platform

I have an google cloud run app hoes need to connect with my clients domain, for this I'm using an Traefik reverse proxy on an VM instance to handle with connection and SSL termination.

My problem is that using a reverse proxy, cloud run throws an google page with 404 error.
Using the cloud run URL everything is fine.

This is my Traefik dynamic config so far:

```
[http]
  [http.routers]
    [http.routers.router0]
      rule = "PathPrefix(`/`)"
      service = "webei"
      entrypoints = ["http"]
    [http.routers.router1]
      rule = "PathPrefix(`/`)"
      service = "webei"
      entrypoints = ["https"]
      [http.routers.router1.tls]
        certResolver = "subdomainCertResolver"

  [http.services]
    # Define how to reach an existing service on our infrastructure
    [http.services.webei.loadBalancer]
      [[http.services.webei.loadBalancer.servers]]
        url = "https://my-cloud-run-url"
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying different solutions to this, I made it work with Nginx and discovered that the problem is in the Host Header.

By default, Traefik uses the Host from the original request, but them, if this Host not match in google Cloud Run, the app is not found.

To solve this I just set the `passHostHeader` value to `false` in Traefik dynamics config.

```
[http.services.myservice.loadBalancer]
  passHostHeader = false
  [[http.services.webei.myservice.servers]]
```